# Merge two date fields in Google Data Studio

Tags: data-visualization, looker-studio

I have the following set-up in a spreadsheet

```
Order | Open date | Completion date | Order status
--------------------------------------------------------------
Ord1  | 01/01/2020 | 01/02/2020      | Success
Ord2  | 01/01/2020 | 01/01/2020      | Rejected by the client
```

In this scenario I have:

- 2 orders opened in Jan
- 1 order success order in Feb
- 1 order rejected in Jan

If I want to put this in a line graph and compare **Total number of orders vs Succes vs  Rejected** , I would have to merge somehow the two date fields in a single date field, correct?

I say this because I have to use a date field for filtering, but if I filter based on **Open date** I don't get the correct date for the two statuses that link to **Completion date** and same the other way around.

Any ideas how to to this comparison in Google Data Studio?

Open date

Comment: Yes you have have to create one date field but before that can you show me one example where the completion date does not work

Comment: When you say you want to merge the date then what will that date variable describe the open/rejected/success? Do you know the labels for which you have to take open date and for which you have to take completion date. If there are less number of labels then you can do it by using a simple case statement.

Comment: For example I want to set-up a chart to show me the open postions in January, and the completed positions by status (Success, Rejected). 

I do the following set-up:
    - Timeseries chart
    - Date range dimenssion: Open date
    - Dimenssion: Open date -> Year Month
    - Metrics:  Count of Orders,  Succes, Rejected.

The Success and Closed are cases that return the **Closed** date when the status is Success or Rejected.

And I will see:
  - 1 Positions Open - *Incorrect**
  - 1 Position Rejected - **Correct**
  - 1 Position Success - **Incorrect**

Comment: Example

https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/f8a48572-ca04-478f-9a77-bc1070584158/page/p1uFB

Answer (score 0):

1. For this **"I want to set-up a chart to show me the open postions in January, and the completed positions by status (Success, Rejected). "**

*First create a filter on opendate. Then draw the line chart as below:*

```
Dimension: comlpleted_date
Breakdown Dimession : status
metric: record count
```

Comment: But I'm still missing the total orders opened in a month. So basically I want Total Opened vs Each status Closed. 


With the solution above I see the breakdown by status, but I'm missing the total Opened.

Comment: For total Count you can keep it at "drill down".